# Custom DataGridView control with popout editor

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I've implemented custom `DataGridViewColumn`, `DataGridViewCell`, and `DataGridViewEditingControl` classes as demonstrated in an [MSDN Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y0).

The problem I have is that while the `DateTimePicker` in the MSDN example is able to pop it's calendar picker out and have it appear over top of the rows below, and cells adjacent to, it; my control is trapped within the space defined by the size of the DGV cell.  My control consists of a textbox and a list of auto-complete suggestions; so I need a way to get the list to appear without making the row several times as tall as normal.

Since I took the example from MSDN and only changed to to the extend of swapping out `DateTimePicker` for `MyControl` and other related changes I assume the magic is happening in the base `DateTimePicker` class; but don't know what I need to change in my control to have it behave the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataGridViewEditingControl` you implement is sized, moved into the cell area, and made visible when the cell enters edit mode. What you need is in addition to the editing control, a "popup control" which you can create when the editing control becomes active and destroy when it becomes not active.

Here's a simple WinForms popup control example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control

However, if all you want is a cell with auto-completion, you can get that for free using the stock `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, or `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/442061-autocompletestringcollection-text-box-datagridview-2-0-a

Comment: I believe the original reason for creating the custom control (for use on regular forms) included the standard autocomplete not being good enough.  Off hand I don't recall if it was performance or functionality that was the limitation.  I need something that performs well when the potential values list contains several thousand elements and that can match substrings anywhere not just from the start.  eg user input of "Jo" should bring up "Smith, John" as a possible value.

Comment: @Tergiver if you have time please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352137/datagridview-editing-control-expand-individually