# DataGridView Editing Control expand individually

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to make your editing control expand beyond height of the owning row with out affecting the row's height and other cell's height. To go over the cells below it. To have some kind of overflow.

Please see the picture. I want editing control to behave like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ToolStripControlHost class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to "simulate" what you want.

On CellBeginEdit you can:

1. create a *Panel* with the desired controls (i.e.: a multiline *TextBox*)
2. create a *ToolStripControlHost* and add your *Panel* to it
3. add your *ToolStripControlHost* to a *ToolStripDropDown*
4. show your *ToolStripDropDown* over the selected cell

Some advices:

- use a single *ToolStripDropDown*
- close your *ToolStripDropDown* on *CellEndEdit* and form *Move/Resize*
- use [GetCellDisplayRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getcelldisplayrectangle%28VS.90%29.aspx) to obtain the rectangle that represents the display area for the selected cell

Comment: Thank you. I am not quite clear with last advice. I have succeeded all but showing panel on correct location over the cell I am editing.

Comment: I got the advice. I still have a problem to have exact location since GetCellDispalyRectangle provdes me with coordinates relative to parent form. I had to do something like this  x = parentForm.Location.X + _customDataGridView.Location.X + cellRectangle.Left + 7;

Comment: I think that GetCellDisplayRectangle returns coordinates relative to your DataGridView. Try using this Show method (i.e. .Show(YourDataGridView, Point): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71tzk45y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx